# Specific VBA Call to DLL

Tags: dll

There is a program called Coolprops I'm using to get refrigerant properties into a spreadsheet. It includes a DLL complied from [this](http://coolprop.sourceforge.net/_static/doxygen/html/_cool_prop_8cpp_source.html#l01042) code. Luckly, it came with a module with the calls to the DLL already setup. I am having no problems getting the program to work out of the box as is.

What I need to do is access the function that is located at line 1042 in the code. I tried copying and modifying one of the calls that came out of the box:

```
Private Declare Function Props_private Lib "K:\Refrigeration\Coolprop\CoolProp.dll" Alias "_Props@32" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Name1 As Long, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As Long, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
```

To this:

```
Private Declare Function set_ref_state Lib "K:\Refrigeration\Coolprop\CoolProp.dll" Alias "set_reference_stateP" (ByVal fluid As String, ByVal ref_state As string)
```

But when I go to call it in my code:

```
Public Function Props(ByVal Output As String, ByVal Name1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Double,     ByVal Name2 As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal fluid As String) As Double

Dim refstate

refstate = set_ref_state("Ammonia", "ASHRAE")

Dim errstring As String
Dim N1, N2 As Integer
Dim Props_temp As Double
Dim L As Long


Props_temp = Props_private(Output, Asc(Left(Name1, 1)), Value1, Asc(Left(Name2, 1)), Value2, fluid)
If Abs(Props_temp > 100000000) Then
    'Make a null-terminated string that is plenty big
    errstring = String(2000, vbNullChar)
    'Get the error string
    L = get_global_param_string_private("errstring", errstring)
    'Display it
    Props = errstring
Else
    Props = Props_temp
End If

End Function
```

The function Props is broken.

My guess is I am missing something simple here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still stuck with this, but you need to change the alias.  Check out the exports from the DLL at https://github.com/ibell/coolprop/blob/master/wrappers/Excel/exports.txt .  It should be `_set_reference_stateS@8`

Ah the joys of windows.

In the future, stack overflow is probably not your best bet for help - check out all the help links at coolprop.org